# Silly Sally likes wearing glasses but not spectacles

Tags: wordplay, word-property

Silly Sally likes balloons, but not party hats.

Silly Sally likes eating pizza, but not burgers.

Silly Sally likes using alliterations, but she doesn't like Metaphors.

Silly Sally likes browsing Reddit, but not Stack Overflow.

What does Silly Sally like?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think the idea here is that:

> Silly Sally likes doubled letters. From the limited examples we have, this makes sense.

BONUS:

> Silly Sally likes Puzzles! But not Questions!

Comment: This is correct! This puzzle is much harder to do when spoken, which is how I heard of it. Good job! (Also it isn't letting me mark it as correct yet. Sorry about that :P )

Comment: @Aryaman You can accept the answer by "clicking on the checkmark".

Comment: @sid there is a [required time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer)(15 minutes) until an answer can be accepted, and at the time OP posted their comment it was likely not past that time yet.

Comment: I heard as Fuzzy Wuzzy I think.  He really likes bookkeepers but not librarians.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 In case you're unaware, bookkeepers are rather different from librarians (to the point where the two are practically unrelated professions). A bookkeeper is more along the lines of an accountant. (This confused me greatly when I was younger.) -- Of course, Silly Sally (and Fuzzy Wuzzy) apparently likes accountants as well, but not quite so much as she likes bookkeepers.