# My eccentric aunt likes lunch but not dinner

Tags: pattern, word-property

My eccentric aunt (not to be confused with [Grandma](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45059/grandma-likes-coffee-but-not-tea) or [Silly Sally](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67272/silly-sally-likes-wearing-glasses-but-not-spectacles)) likes some things but dislikes others:

- She likes lunch but dislikes dinner.
- She likes blue, but dislikes green.
- She likes spicy things but dislikes pepper.
- She likes rain, but dislikes drizzle.
- She likes the ocean but dislikes salt water.
- She likes animals but dislikes plants.
- She likes goats, but dislikes horses.
- She likes chipmunks, but dislikes squirrels.
- She likes bugs, but dislikes insects.
- She likes wine, but dislikes fermented fruit juice.
- She likes celebratory events, but dislikes parties.

What, exactly, is it that she dislikes?

**Hint 1:**

> She dislikes horses and grassy fields, but she *despises* polo.

**Hint 2:**

> She dislikes **every** horse. She also dislikes lunches, blues, spiciness, and wines. She enjoys when it rains, and she likes oceans.

**Hint 3**

> She dislikes bushes, but she truly *despises* trees. Similarly, she dislikes teeter-totters, but she *despises* seesaws.

Comment: Does she dislike an individual singular horse, or only horses as a group?

Comment: @Ertai87 If nobody gets the answer by midday tomorrow, I'll answer your question in another hint. (I'm trying to limit myself to one hint per day.)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, all the statements except the last one follow the rule that she doesn't like things with two letters in them (Unlike Silly Sally, these letters can be anywhere in the word.)

Comment: @Aryaman plants and horses also defy that rule.

Comment: My mad. I guess I was being very silly.

Comment: @R.D "Horses" has 2 s's.  Hence my comment above.

Comment: @Aryaman - Also note that she _likes_ celebratory events, which would defy that rule as well.

Comment: Dagnabbit every time I think I am onto something another line refutes it... +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your eccentric aunt dislike

> Words with consecutive letters close to each other on a keyboard?

That is:

> dinn**er**
>  g**ree**n
>  pepp**er**
>  **dr**izzle
>  **sa**lt **wa**t**er**
>  **pl**ants
>  hor**ses**
>  sq**ui**r**re**ls
>  in**se**cts
>  f**er**ment**ed** **frui**t **jui**ce
>  pa**rt**i**es**

And

> gr**as**sy fiel**ds**
>  **polo**
>  hor**se**
>  lunch**es**
>  blu**es**
>  spicin**ess**
>  win**es**
>  bush**es**
>  tr**ees**
>  teet**er**-tott**er**s
>  **seesaws**

I guess your aunt would really hate REDRESSED ISSUES but much prefer PROBLEMS NOW CLEAR!

Comment: personally I think TH doesn't count against your idea +1

Comment: You have nailed it. (TH doesn't count)

Comment: Great, updated to note!